# Image index not always changes

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I'm trying to code simple memory game in Windows Forms but I've met a simple problem that somehow I can't pass.
This is a single button code(they all look very similar):

```
    Match CheckForMatches = new Match();
    private void Pathfinder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForMatches.AddButton(Pathfinder);
        CheckForMatches.Matched();
    }
```

(where CheckForMatches object is shared between all buttons in given form)

And here are called methods codes:

```
    public void AddButton(Button newButton)          
    {
        if (firstButtonPressed == null)
        {
            firstButtonPressed = newButton;
            firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;                      //uncovering card
        }
        else
        { 
            secondButtonPressed = newButton;
            secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public bool Matched()
    {
        if (firstButtonPressed != null && secondButtonPressed != null )
        {
            if (firstButtonPressed.Name != secondButtonPressed.Name)
            {
                if (firstButtonPressed.Text == secondButtonPressed.Text)
                {
                    DisposeButtons();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    NullButtons();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now this method call one of two others, depending if last 2 clicked buttons are a pair or not(basing on their name and text):

This in case of succes disposes buttons and null Match class variables:

```
    public void DisposeButtons()
    {
        firstButtonPressed.Dispose();
        secondButtonPressed.Dispose();

        firstButtonPressed = null;
        secondButtonPressed = null;
    }
```

This is case of failure covers cards and also nulls Match class variables:

```
    public void NullButtons()
    {
        firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 1;              //covering cards
        secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 1;

        firstButtonPressed = null;
        secondButtonPressed = null;
    }
```

The point is, no matter where I place Thread.Sleep(1000), user can never see second card he choses. He always see the first one and then, when he choses second one, either both cards are disposed(app is freezing due to that delay) or the first one becomes covered, without uncovering the second one.

EDIT:
I added output to debugger window, so now method AddButton looks like this:

```
        public void AddButton(Button newButton)
    {
        if (firstButtonPressed == null)
        {
            firstButtonPressed = newButton;
            Debug.WriteLine("Before index chaning: " + firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;                      //uncovering card
            Debug.WriteLine("After index chaning: " + firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
        }
        else
        { 
            secondButtonPressed = newButton;
            Debug.WriteLine("Before index chaning: " + secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("After index chaning: " + secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

I can see there, that ImageIndex buttons' property actually changes between 1 and 0. However, in practice, it's only visible when first if block of this method is called. I would be grateful for answering why and how to change that.

Comment: I would advise you to use another thread to manage flipping the card and put the timer in there so that you don't freeze your application.

Comment: @CyanCoding actually I want to freeze it for a moment so user can see the second card he chose

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out maybe not best solution, but it works. I simply forced button to refresh.
Correct form of AddButton method is:

```
    public void AddButton(Button newButton)
    {
        if (firstButtonPressed == null)
        {
            firstButtonPressed = newButton;
            Debug.WriteLine("Before index changing: " + firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;                                           //uncovering card
            Debug.WriteLine("After index changing: " + firstButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
        }
        else
        { 
            secondButtonPressed = newButton;
            Debug.WriteLine("Before index changing: " + secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex = 0;
            secondButtonPressed.Refresh();
            Debug.WriteLine("After index changing: " + secondButtonPressed.ImageIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will be useful for someone one day.